# Compress non digested SASS assets rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have some assets that I need to keep out of the asset pipeline but still need to be compressed, specifically some SASS files. I have achieved this for my non digested JS which looks something like this:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/non_digest/*"].each do |asset|
   asset_name = File.basename(asset)
   asset_output = "#{Rails.root}/public/external/#{asset_name}"
   asset_uglified = Uglifier.compile(File.read(asset))
   File.open(asset_output, 'w') {|a| a.write(asset_uglified) }
end
```

This is included in my initializers.

Is it possible to use Sprockets to do the same for my non digested SASS files? I've taken a quick look at `Sprockets::SassCompressor` but haven't been able to get it to work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the sass gem installed you can do the following:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/non_digest/*"].each do |asset|
  asset_name = File.basename(asset)
  asset_output = "#{Rails.root}/public/external/#{asset_name.gsub('.scss', '.css')}"
  asset_minified = Sass::Engine.new(File.read(asset), syntax: :scss, style: :compressed).render
  File.open(asset_output, 'w') {|a| a.write(asset_minified) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sprockets-sass gem ? It works great with SASS and SCSS . Currently supports only sprockets 2.x and 3.x .  It also provides a compressor .

Comment: Hi @rada I ended up using `Sass::Engine` provided by the `sass` gem which does the job!

Comment: Ok. However sprockets-sass has some adițional features that allows you to import files deeply nested and from globbed directories. And also has a cache store for caching files. And the importer is able to import even other type of files If those files have an associated engine or transformer. You should really check it out.  Disclaimer : i am a contributor to that gem :)